# Difficulty referring to class function

Tags: php, class, object

I need to call a function `someFunction()` how do I refer to it when it is in the following class structures?

```
abstract class A
{
    protected $session;
    protected $model;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $session = new classSession;
        $model = new classModel;
    }
}

class classModel
{
    $this->session->someFunction();
}
```

I've tried using `$this->session->someFunction()` but it does not work!

Comment: Where is `someFunction` defined?  What is `classModel`?  Why do you just have a line of code inside it?  You need a function in there.  Is `classModel` supposed to `extend A`?  What is `classSession`?  How does it "not work"?  What error(s) do you get?

Comment: sorry im trying to summarize my code here - it is in the context of a function...the problem is definitely with how I am referencing the function

Comment: Should your `class classModel` really be `class classModel extends A`?

Comment: In `A`'s constructor, you need to set `$this->session`, not `$session`.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you need to put it within the context of a function - code cannot exist on its own within a class body. Secondly, for anything in `classModel` to access `$session`, `classModel` has to extend class `A`. You end up with something like this:

```
class classModel extends A
{
    public function foo()
    {
        $this->session->someFunction();
    }
}
```

So for `$this->session->someFunction();` to execute, you'd do this:

```
$model = new classModel();
$model->foo();
```